# Why is my app crashing with `NumberFormatException`?

Tags: java, android

My app is crashing on click admission layout but it's not crashing with all login credential only with some ID it's crashing. It completely depends on login account. I have 100s of account and I tried login with all different credential only it's crashing with few login accounts.

Here are the logs:

```
 LIST_ADMISSION: [ListEnquiryItem{paid_fees = '',fname = '',course_id = '5',address = 'thank you for',discount_fees = '',course_name = '11th',batch_id = '4',subject = 'Science,Hindi,English',total_fees = '10000',mobile = '9999999999',photo = 'http://webytechno.com/ClassBro/admin/uploads/1536226227055.jpg',medium = '',date1 = '2018-09-06',fmobile = '',reference = '',password = 'g3gkba',batch_name = 'Evening's Batch',remaining_fees = '10000',school = '',sname = 'adil',dob = '2018-09-06',id = '402',email = '',username = 'adilfrn'}, ListEnquiryItem{paid_fees = '9000',fname = 'Kasim mulla',course_id = '30',address = 'jdv jabs jdbbs',discount_fees = '500',course_name = 'tybms',batch_id = '36',subject = 'sub1,sub2,sub3',total_fees = '12000',mobile = '7414969600',photo = 'http://webytechno.com/ClassBro/admin/uploads/1526708605633.jpg',medium = 'English',date1 = '2018-05-19',fmobile = '8355893913',reference = 'Imram',password = 'jy8g6t',batch_name = 'tybms morning',remaining_fees = '2500',school = 'vvuc',sname = 'Daud',dob = '2018-05-19',id = '57',email = 'daud@gmail.con',username = 'pmd17t'}, ListEnquiryItem{paid_fees = '1000',fname = 'cyz',course_id = '1',address = 'gaahha',discount_fees = '500',course_name = '10th class',batch_id = '2',subject = 'English,Hindi,Gujarati,Science',total_fees = '25000',mobile = '9875461312',photo = 'http://webytechno.com/ClassBro/admin/uploads/1525085910070.jpg',medium = 'eng',date1 = '2018-04-30',fmobile = '0784945431',reference = 'friend',password = 'azv3r2',batch_name = 'CBSE',remaining_fees = '23500',school = 'abc',sname = 'dev',dob = '2018-04-30',id = '9',email = 'd@gmail.com',username = 'lgr6vb'}, ListEnquiryItem{paid_fees = '1000',fname = 'snsnsns',course_id = '1',address = 'adajan',discount_fees = '500',course_name = '10th class',batch_id = '2',subject = 'English,Hindi,Gujarati,Science',total_fees = '25000',mobile = '4799497979',photo = 'http://webytechno.com/ClassBro/admin/uploads/1525418210297.jpg',medium = 'xyz',date1 = '2018-05-04',fmobile = '4949494994',reference = 'friend',password = 'dij0n0',batch_name = 'CBSE',remaining_fees = '23500',school = 'abc',sname = 'dev',dob = '2018-04-30',id = '20',email = 'd@gmail.com',username = '6wrecl'}, ListEnquiryItem{paid_fees = '16000',fname = 'Tank',course_id = '1',address = 'adajan',discount_fees = '500',course_name = '10th class',batch_id = '2',subject = 'Hindi,Gujarati,Science',total_fees = '25000',mobile = '9601582889',photo = 'http://webytechno.com/ClassBro/admin/uploads/1525426112538.jpg',medium = 'eng',date1 = '2018-05-04',fmobile = '9608546322',reference = 'friend',password = '3rxeqd',batch_name = 'CBSE',remaining_fees = '8500',school = 'abc',sname = 'Devilal',dob = '2018-03-07',id = '28',email = 'devil@gmail.com',username = 'r3f7t0'}, ListEnquiryItem{paid_fees = '1000',fname = 'Deepak',course_id = '1',address = 'borivali',discount_fees = '0',course_name = '10th class',batch_id = '5',subject = 'English,Hindi,Gujarati,Maths',total_fees = '5000',mobile = '9619073803',photo = 'http://webytechno.com/ClassBro/admin/uploads/54350-koala.jpg',medium = 'English',date1 = '2018-04-26',fmobile = '7021327803',reference = 'friend',password = '1234',batch_name = 'night batches',remaining_fees = '4000',school = 'J.B.Khot High School',sname = 'Dhaval',dob = '2018-04-25',id = '3',email = 'dhavalvyas08@gm',username = 'dhaval'}, ListEnquiryItem{paid_fees = '1000',fname = 'cyz',course_id = '1',address = 'gaahha',discount_fees = '5000',course_name = '10th class',batch_id = '4',subject = 'Hindi,Gujarati,Science',total_fees = '25000',mobile = '9875461312',photo = 'http://webytechno.com/ClassBro/admin/uploads/1525418584333.jpg',medium = 'sjsns',date1 = '2018-05-04',fmobile = '0784945431',reference = 'friend',password = 'lkq4rx',batch_name = 'Evening's Batch',remaining_fees = '19000',school = 'BBka',sname = 'Dhaval',dob = '2018-04-30',id = '21',email = 'd@gmail.com',username = 'tukw2o'}, ListEnquiryItem{paid_fees = '500',fname = 'kale',course_id = '27',address = 'malad',discount_fees = '500',course_name = 'H S C',batch_i
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.classbro.student.admin, PID: 9292
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at app.student.com.studentmanagement.adapter.AdmissionListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AdmissionListAdapter.java:56)
        at app.student.com.studentmanagement.adapter.AdmissionListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AdmissionListAdapter.java:22)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` This mean your input string is empty, and an empty string is not a valid number

Comment: @Ferrybig Thanks for help but with other account it's working perfectly

Comment: in some cases you are trying to parse empty string into int, obviously. Which means that there is a problem with your code. `AdmissionListAdapter.java:56`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

This happens, because you have called `Integer.parseInt` with an empty String.

Since this happens only with a few accounts i assume that their password is empty and you try to login sending an empty password, which would be ok if you accepted String the password as the Strings as they are sent instead of trying to convert them to Integer.

Comment: Can you tell what i need to do because it's only crashing with few account.

Comment: @A.Gun Either you force every ID/password/etc what you are using in parseInt to be a non-empty, numerical String or you get rid of parseInt and check for String equality instead

Comment: thanks man you solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using `parseInt()` method and pass String variables to it. If your IDs are String, use a String variable for that.

Comment: Ok will check and let you know